# Form field arrays validate individually with jQuery, but then form won't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

This is my first post, so please be kind.  :-)

I have a form with several arrays and other items.  Some form fields can be entered more than once which is why they are arrays.  I am using Jquery 1.11.1 and jquery validate.  Two of my arrays are only required depending on a choice from a drop-down list.  If the correct items are not filled in or selected, I get all of the error messages I expect.  And, when all items are completed, all error messages are gone.

The problem is, the form will not then submit. I believe it has something to do with the "conditional" arrays because I have another form where the arrays are all required and it works fine.

This has been driving me crazy for a while now - long enough to post the   question here.  I have looked at many, many postings here and haven't found anyone with my exact problem.

I'm hoping someone can help.

Here is the HTML form (the JS and validation are included before the form):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ggsghpcc.sgt-inc.com/cmct/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
  numComps = 1;
  function showCampaigns(id)  {
  var mission1 = "missionOne";
  var mission2 = "missionTwo";
  var compNumber = id.slice(10);
  var selection = document.getElementById(id).value;
  if (selection == "missionOne")  {
     document.getElementById(selection + "_" + compNumber).style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById(mission2 + "_" + compNumber).style.display = "none";}

  if (selection == "missionTwo")  {
     document.getElementById(selection + "_" + compNumber).style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById(mission1 + "_" + compNumber).style.display = "none";  }
 }
$(document).ready(function()  {

  var u_campaignMissionOne = new Array;
  var u_campaignMissionTwo = new Array;
  var u_dataset = new Array;
  var u_mission = new Array; 
  var FS = 1;
  var x = 2;
  var u_variable = new Array;
  var u_intIndex = new Array;


  $("#submitData").validate({
  rules: {
      'u_variable[]': {
          required: true
      },
      'u_intIndex[]': {
          required: true,
          min: 1
      }, 
      'u_mission[]': {
          required: true
      },
      'u_campaignMissionOne[]': {
          required: function(element) {
              var setNumber = $(element).attr('id');
              var setNum = "comp" + setNumber.slice(21);
              var missionNum = "u_mission_" + setNumber.slice(21);
                return $((document.getElementById(missionNum).value) == 'MissionOne');
                    }  
      },
      'u_campaignMissionTwo[]': {
          required: function(element) {
              var setNumber = $(element).attr('id');
              var setNum = "comp" + setNumber.slice(21);
              var missionNum = "u_mission_" + setNumber.slice(21);
            return $((document.getElementById(missionNum).value) == 'MissionTwo');
                    }  
      },
      'u_dataSet[]': {
          required: true
      }
  },
  messages: {
      'u_variable[]': {
          required:"  Please enter a variable",
      },
      'u_intIndex[]': {
          required:"   Please enter a time interval",
      },
      'u_mission[]': {
          required:"   Please select a mission"
      },
      'u_campaignMissionOne[]': {
          required:"   Please select a Mission One campaign"
      },
      'u_campaignMissionTwo[]': {
          required:"   Please select a Mission Two campaign"
      },
      'u_dataSet[]': {
          required:"   Please select a data set"
      }
  },
  wrapper: 'span',
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
  error.css({'padding-left':'10px','padding-top':'0.5em','padding-bottom':'2px', 'color': 'red', 'font-style':'italic', 'font-size':'14px', 'width': '330px', 'float': 'right'});

    error.insertAfter(element);
  }
  });
 });

</script>
<h2>Submit data</h2>
<div class="full-width-content-item">

<form id="submitData" action="alert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
 <div id="formStuff" style="margin:0; padding:0; display:inline;">
 <div style="height:40px; width:100%;"></div>
<div id="comp1">
 <fieldset><legend>Data</legend>
 <div id="intervalIndex">
        <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Time index*</label></div>
        <input type="text" size="10" id="u_intIndex_1" name="u_intIndex[]" placeholder="Integer value > 0" value=""/>
 </div><!--end intervalIndex--><br clear="right" />
 <div id="variable">
        <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Variable*</label></div>
        <input type="text" id="u_variable_1" name="u_variable[]" class="u_variable" value="" />
 </div><!--end variable--><br clear="right" />
 <div>
    <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Mission*</label> </div>
        <select name="u_mission[]" id="u_mission_1" onchange="showCampaigns(this.id);">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="missionOne"  >Mission One</option>
            <option value="missionTwo"  >Mission Two</option>
        </select>
 </div><br clear="right" />
 <div class="campaign"> 
     <div class="missionOne" id="missionOne_1" style="height:3.0em; display:none;">
        <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Mission One Campaign*</label></div>
            <select name="u_campaignMissionOne[]" id="u_campaignMissionOne_1" >
                <option value="">Please select</option>                        
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-1" >Campaign-MissionOne-1</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-2" >Campaign-MissionOne-2</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-3" >Campaign-MissionOne-3</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-4" >Campaign-MissionOne-4</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-5" >Campaign-MissionOne-5</option>

            </select>
    </div>
     <div class="missionTwo" id="missionTwo_1" style="display:none;">
        <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Mission Two Campaign*</label></div>
            <select name="u_campaignMissionTwo[]" id="u_campaignMissionTwo_1">
                <option value="">Please select</option>                        
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-1" >Campaign-MissionTwo-1</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-2" >Campaign-MissionTwo-2</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-3" >Campaign-MissionTwo-3</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-4" >Campaign-MissionTwo-4</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-5" >Campaign-MissionTwo-5</option>
            </select>                    
     </div>
 </div><!--end class=campaign--><br clear="right" />
 <div>
    <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Data set*</label>  </div>
        <select name="u_dataSet[]" id="u_dataSet_1">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="dataSet1"  >dataSet 1</option>
            <option value="dataSet2"  >dataSet 2</option>
            <option value="dataSet3"  >dataSet 3</option>
            <option value="dataSet4"  >dataSet 4</option>
            <option value="dataSet5"  >dataSet 5</option>
        </select>
 </div><br clear="right" />
 </fieldset></div><!--end comp1 div-->
 <div style="height:40px; width:100%;"></div>
 <div id="comp2">
 <fieldset><legend>Data</legend>
 <div id="intervalIndex">
        <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Time index*</label></div>
        <input type="text" size="10" id="u_intIndex_2" name="u_intIndex[]" placeholder="Integer value > 0" value=""/>
 </div><!--end intervalIndex--><br clear="right" />
 <div id="variable">
        <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Variable*</label></div>
        <input type="text" id="u_variable_2" name="u_variable[]" value="" />
 </div><!--end variable--><br clear="right" />
 <div>
    <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Mission*</label></div>
        <select name="u_mission[]" id="u_mission_2" onchange="showCampaigns(this.id);">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="missionOne"  >Mission One</option>
            <option value="missionTwo"  >Mission Two</option>
        </select>
 </div><br clear="right" />
 <div class="campaign"> 
     <div class="missionOne" id="missionOne_2" style="height:3.0em; display:none;">
        <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Mission One Campaign*</label></div>
            <select name="u_campaignMissionOne[]" id="u_campaignMissionOne_2" >
                <option value="">Please select</option>                        
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-1" >Campaign-MissionOne-1</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-2" >Campaign-MissionOne-2</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-3" >Campaign-MissionOne-3</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-4" >Campaign-MissionOne-4</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionOne-5" >Campaign-MissionOne-5</option>

            </select>
    </div>
     <div class="missionTwo" id="missionTwo_2" style="display:none;">
        <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Mission Two Campaign*</label></div>
            <select name="u_campaignMissionTwo[]" id="u_campaignMissionTwo_2">
                <option value="">Please select</option>                        
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-1" >Campaign-MissionTwo-1</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-2" >Campaign-MissionTwo-2</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-3" >Campaign-MissionTwo-3</option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-4" >Campaign-MissionTwo-4<option>
                <option value="Campaign-MissionTwo-5" >Campaign-MissionTwo-5<option>
            </select>                    
     </div>
 </div><!--end class=campaign--><br clear="right" />
 <div>
    <div class="fieldLabel"><label class="control-label">Data set*</label></div>
        <select name="u_dataSet[]" id="u_dataSet_2">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="dataSet1"  >dataSet 1</option>
            <option value="dataSet2"  >dataSet 2</option>
            <option value="dataSet3"  >dataSet 3</option>
            <option value="dataSet4"  >dataSet 4</option>
            <option value="dataSet5"  >dataSet 5</option>
        </select>
 </div><br clear="right" />
</fieldset></div><!--end comp2 div-->
 <div style="height:20px; width:100%;"></div>

<button type="submit" >Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi! Just a few questions. Does it submit if you remove your jqueryValidate code? Also, what does alert.php do? Your calling it as your submit action in your form declaration.

Comment: alert.php doesn't do anything.  When I test the form on my server, I get a "not found" error which tells me that the form at least submitted and looked for it.  My plan was to just echo "Form submitted" on the page if the form was submitted.  Yes, if I take out all of the validation code, it submits and I get the "alert.php was not found on this server." error.

Comment: I guess your problem is there. Your action parameter should point to some URL where you're making the post request.

Comment: I don't think so, because with the validation code, the submit button doesn't do anything after all fields are entered and the error messages are gone.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - it looks like it works as expected. Check out [This JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/42qmenh0/)

Comment: When you select a Mission, a new dropdown list is supposed to appear for selection of a Campaign.  It's not doing that in the jsfiddle. Not sure why not. It works on my server.

Comment: I also edited the code a bit and re-posted it above.  It had an error in one of the ids.